# How can you correlate data back and forth?

Tags: python, dataframe

How can you correlate data back and forth without losing where the data originates from. I want to extract the "problem" column for nlp analysis but I want to keep what machine that "problem" came from somewhere. I want to be able to correlate the tokenized words back to the sentence they came from back to the machine it came from.

| asset | number | problem |
| --- | --- | --- |
| machine 1 | wo134214 | "machine is broken" |
| machine 1 | wo134214 | "machine is not working" |
| machine 1 | wo134432 | "machine is getting hot" |

I want this to output to:

```py
{'Number': ["wo134214", "wo134432"],
 'Asset': ["machine1"],
 'Problem': ["machine is broken",
  "machine is not working",
  "machine is getting hot"]}
```

Currently it will make duplicates. Eventually I want to make another tab that has Words after tokenization. I just am not sure how to make sure there is trail of records showing where this problem is from. As in what machine did this problem come from.

My end goal output is to be able to make a chord diagram which shows most used words -> what sentence it came from -> what machine this sentence came from.

Comment: imho your question is hard to understand. Can you please provide an example with your code, and very important an example of input and how your desired output should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Producing desired output

If you want a dict as output **exactly like you requested** above (assuming you want to group only by `"asset"`), you can do it like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'number': ["wo134214", "wo134214", "wo134432"],
 'asset': ["machine1", "machine1", "machine1"],
 'problem': ["machine is broken",
  "machine is not working",
  "machine is getting hot"]})

grouped = df.groupby(["asset"])

for group, grouped_values in grouped:
  desired_output_dict = dict()
  desired_output_dict["asset"] = list(group) # if you really want it to be a list, however is always len=1
  desired_output_dict["number"] = grouped_values["number"].unique().tolist() # unique to get rid of dublicates
  desired_output_dict["problem"] = grouped_values["problem"].unique().tolist() # unique to get rid of dublicates
  print(desired_output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{
'asset': ['machine1'],
'number': ['wo134214', 'wo134432'],
'problem': ['machine is broken', 'machine is not working', 'machine is getting hot']
}
```

you should check out [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) for better understanding

## Overall problem

### 1 Solutionwith two lists

Regarding the overal problem, it may be easier to have two separate list, one for problems, and one for origins which have the same order. And the connection between them is the index.

```py
origin = [ {'asset': ['machine1'],'number': ['wo134214', 'wo134432']}, ...other origins ]
problem = [ ['machine is broken', 'machine is not working', 'machine is getting hot'], ...other problems ]

print(f"the {problem[0]} has {origin[0]}")
print(f"the {problem[1]} has {origin[1]}")
...
```

Similar, you can do it with dicts inestead by giving individual indexes as keys.

### 2 Make your own list class with origin

You could also [inherit from list](https://realpython.com/inherit-python-list/), but may be overengineered. Anywasy, here is a small example:

```py
class List_with_origin(list):
  def set_origin(self, d):
    self.origin = d

  def get_origin(self):
    return self.origin

  # other list functions, see https://realpython.com/inherit-python-list

problem = List_with_origin(desired_output_dict["problem"]) #
problem.set_origin({"number": desired_output_dict["number"], "asset": desired_output_dict["asset"]})

print(problem) # behaves like a normal list...
print(problem.get_origin()) # ...but has a method for showing the origin
```

Would that solve your problems?

Comment: Yeah this helped. Although in my code I did `group` on its own rather than have it be a list. Whenever it was turned into a list it would split the string into a list of the singular letters.

Comment: I'm glad that i could help. Consider accept my answer so that the question is closed